# Send Whatsapp notification message to phone field

Tags: process-builder, service, digital-engagement

I am trying to configure a process builder to send a whatsapp message (Digital Engagement) once the conditions are met. Although the process is executed correctly and the MessagingEndUser is created the message never is sent. At the same time, if I modify the format of the phone field to be aligned with this pattern **whatsapp:+(countryCode)(phoneNumber)** the message surprisingly is sent.

Do you know if it is required to use that format? I am not able to find nothing inside the documentation...

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.livemessage_automatic_message_notifications_process.htm&type=5

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried all possible combinations and I only got the message delivered using this pattern whatsapp:+dDI+dDD+phoneNumber

Comment: Same here, did you see anything about it on the documentation?